# Exclude Replacement character from solr search result

Tags: solr, full-text-search, dspace

While searching in my dspace server after running dspace filter-media, I see a lot of replacement character. How can I ignore them, or say replace them with empty string?

My first idea was to do the following:

```
    <fieldType name="title" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="�" replacement=""/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

But this still shows the replacement character "�" in the search results.

Comment: It'll filter when you index (not when searching / querying - that would be in the `query` analyzer), so you'll have to reindex to replace it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The analyzer you posted is doing the replacement work only at index time, so that means for each document that is indexed, for each field associated with that type, that replacement occurs.

If you mean that you still see some records, coming from Solr, with those characters that means probably the chain is not working (e.g. the regular expression in the filter doesn't catch / replace the right characters)

I have some doubt about your questions because at the end you say:

> But I realized this is used to filter the search query whereas I need to filter out the results.

- the replacement filter is used at index time, and **not** a query time
- the analyzer (index or query) is not supposed to filter our results, it's not its role. The analyzer processes (index time) documents that are going to be indexed, and (query time) the incoming query strings.

"Filter out the results" is something that is done at query time, using filters. If (trying to interpret your doubt) you want those documents that contain those characters to be excluded from the indexing phase, then you can

- work on the client side (avoid to send them to Solr)
- write an *UpdateRequestProcessor* which does that kind of filtering

Comment: I just don't want to see "�"  on my search result, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Then the second part of my answer is what you need (UpdateRequestProcessor). It is a component that allows you to manipulate the document before it gets indexed. There you can do whatever you want, including chars removal

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Which class should I use? "IgnoreFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" is the closest I could come, which matches the description.

Comment: No I guess there is nothing already built for your need. If I got you, you don t want the doc indexed at all

Comment: I want Replacement character removed from the search results, so I guess it should be done before indexing. Any idea how I might do that? Again thank you very much for patiently everything.